# ValueError: Length of values (221) does not match length of index (189)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I am trying to add my lists to columns in my dataframes but some of the lists have more data in them compared to others. I am getting the following error:

```
 ValueError: Length of values (221) does not match length of index (189)
```

The data in each column does match with eachother so it all matches up in a row. Is there a way to get this to work with the data? Maybe add NaN values or null?

Sample List 1:

```
['Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation', 'Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation']
```

Sample List 2:

```
['Windows Management Instrumentation', 'XSL Script Processing', 'Domain Policy Modification', 'Forge Web Credentials']
```

Sample List 3:

```
['Blue MockingBird', 'FIN6']
```

Expected data-frame:

```
Tactic                   Name                               Actor
Defense Evasion       Windows Management Instrumentation      Blue Mocking Bird
Privilege Escalation   XSL Script Processing                  
Defense Evasion        Domain Policy Modification             Fin 6
Privilege Escalation    Forge Web Credentials
```

Comment: Please share a sample of all lists with expected output.

Comment: Your sample data has both lists of equal length. I don't think this is the case. Please correct and add proper sample data from which the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I have now updated with some sample data

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Apologies, one of the Actors was in the wrong location. That is is matches on the list. So when its exported it knows what is supposed to be matched with what

Comment: What is the logic for matching those rows?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a dataframe that has columns as lists,  the expanding using `explode()` to get to you desired output.  In this case both of your lists are of same length,  it would still work where lists are not same length.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Tactic":[['Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation', 'Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation']],
             "Name":[['Windows Management Instrumentation', 'XSL Script Processing', 'Domain Policy Modification', 'Forge Web Credentials']]})

df = df["Tactic"].explode().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame().join(df["Name"].explode().reset_index(drop=True))

print(df.to_string())
```

### output

```
                 Tactic                                Name
0       Defense Evasion  Windows Management Instrumentation
1  Privilege Escalation               XSL Script Processing
2       Defense Evasion          Domain Policy Modification
3  Privilege Escalation               Forge Web Credentials
```

If you want to expand to columns, use `pd.Series`

```
import numpy as np
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([{"data":np.random.randint(1,10,s), "static":"a value"} for s in np.random.randint(1,10, 10)])
df = df.join(df.data.apply(pd.Series))
```

### output

```
                          data   static    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
0                          [1]  a value  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1        [4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5]  a value  4.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  5.0  4.0  5.0  NaN  NaN
2                          [1]  a value  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3                          [2]  a value  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     [7, 8, 4, 8, 7, 6, 2, 1]  a value  7.0  8.0  4.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  2.0  1.0  NaN
5     [1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 1, 8, 1]  a value  1.0  2.0  6.0  3.0  9.0  1.0  8.0  1.0  NaN
6        [3, 3, 9, 4, 5, 5, 7]  a value  3.0  3.0  9.0  4.0  5.0  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
7              [2, 8, 1, 9, 5]  a value  2.0  8.0  1.0  9.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  [8, 7, 7, 9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 1]  a value  8.0  7.0  7.0  9.0  3.0  6.0  1.0  7.0  1.0
9                          [7]  a value  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Please wait for OP to come with exact requirements.

Comment: ok - have updated and also provided answer that matches OP statement of requirement that is different that data samples provided

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
In [247]: l1 = ['Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation', 'Defense Evasion', 'Privilege Escalation']    
In [248]: l2 = ['Windows Management Instrumentation', 'XSL Script Processing', 'Domain Policy Modification', 'Forge Web Credentials']    
In [249]: l3 = ['Blue MockingBird', 'FIN6']

In [245]: ans = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Tactic':l1, 'Name': l2, 'Actor': l3}, orient='index').T

In [246]: ans
Out[246]: 
                 Tactic                                Name             Actor
0       Defense Evasion  Windows Management Instrumentation  Blue MockingBird
1  Privilege Escalation               XSL Script Processing              FIN6
2       Defense Evasion          Domain Policy Modification              None
3  Privilege Escalation               Forge Web Credentials              None
```

**OR**, use `pd.Series`:

```
In [252]: ans = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Tactic':pd.Series(l1), 'Name': pd.Series(l2), 'Actor': pd.Series(l3)})

In [253]: ans
Out[253]: 
                 Tactic                                Name             Actor
0       Defense Evasion  Windows Management Instrumentation  Blue MockingBird
1  Privilege Escalation               XSL Script Processing              FIN6
2       Defense Evasion          Domain Policy Modification               NaN
3  Privilege Escalation               Forge Web Credentials               NaN
```